# java matcher regex not working

Tags: java, pattern-matching

It seems an easy problem but I really can't understand why it is not working.
A typical example of how to fetch emails with `Java` from a text, I would like the code to output emails found but I got no output instead, see the code excerpt:

```
package regex;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class EsempioPatternMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

String emails = "info@mariorossi.it))"+
        "adfdagfgaafgValidator(\"paolo.pa@paolorossi.it\"));"+
        "rintlnx.rerewqwrwe\"mario@bianchi.it\"));";


        String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z] {2,})";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(emails);

        while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());

        }
    }
```

I thought it was the `regex` but as a matter of fact, even when I make it very easy, I will not output anything. It seems `m.find()` is not matching anything.
I have seen other examples and this seems to be a common code to handle such situation...what am I doing so wrong?

Thanks!
E

Comment: you need to get rid of the space between the tld and `{2,}`

Comment: GOT ME  !!!! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works on my machine.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class EsempioPatternMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

String emails = "info@mariorossi.it))"+
        "adfdagfgaafgValidator(\"paolo.pa@paolorossi.it\"));"+
        "rintlnx.rerewqwrwe\"mario@bianchi.it\"));";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(emails);

        while (m.find( ))
        System.out.println(m.group());

        }
    }
```

Hope this Helps!

Regards,
Eby J

Comment: thanks, but the main error was my stupid mistake highlighted  in previous comment